# JsTree's nodes are not using using icons specified in Types plugin in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jstree

In my application I have the following jsTree created

```
$('#categoryTree').jstree({
    plugins: ['themes', 'html_data', 'contextmenu', 'ui', 'types'],
    contextmenu: {
        items: ContextMenuItems
    },
    ui: {
        select_limit: 0
    },
    themes: {
        theme: 'classic'
    },
    types: {
        type_attr: 'nodetype',
        types: {
            category: {
                icon: { image: baseUrl + '/Images/folder.png' }
            },

            testcase: {
                icon: { image: baseUrl + '/Images/hlp.png' }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Everything is working great on FF and Chrome, category nodes use the specified `folder.png` and test case nodes use `hlp.png` as their icons.

However, Internet explorer does not seem to respect this and it uses the default icon for ALL nodes.  Anyone have any ideas how to force IE to use the correct icons for the type, and not use the default icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this at the top of your page to disable quirks mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

reference:
http://groups.google.com/group/jstree/browse_thread/thread/e049c1a6eb24b44a

Comment: That seems to fix it, along with a LOT of random IE oddities that were occurring for no reason!